# How to set a single image for an android ListView background?

Tags: android, background, android-listview

I have used this code for the row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@drawable/bckimage"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

and this is for the class that builds the list:

```
public class ListTestActivity extends ListActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] myArray = new String[] {...};

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listlayout,myArray));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setCacheColorHint(0);
    listView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
//. . .
});

}
}
```

This shows an image for each row, not for the whole background. How can I add a single image for background? I saw several methods in here also but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the image as the background for the `ListView` element instead:

```
getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);
```

Your list rows probably hide the background image. Also add:

```
getListView().setCacheColorHint(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Still have the same problem :(

Comment: Yes... I have tested that, but result doesn't change. It shows an image per raw... anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @Grant Well, have you removed the  `android:background="@drawable/bckimage"` declaration from the `TextView` in your row layout?

Comment: No... do I need to remove that?

Comment: @Grant Yes, that will override the list background otherwise.

Comment: `android.R.color.transparent` caused me problems when scrolling, replacing it with `Color.TRANSPARENT` however worked well.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, set background to your list and not to the row layout.

You can set background to your list in following way:

```
((ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bckimage);
```

Whenever you are using ListActivity, it have ListView with id "list".

Comment: Can you please explain bit more ? I'm just started to learn Android programming...

Comment: You not using only "Activity".. you using "ListActivity".. So in ListActivity, you already have ListView with id "list".. In that list, you adding list items which have layout you mentioned.. and you setting bg to row layout and not to ListView.. So remove bg from row layout and add bg to ListView..